# Can neutrons detect the diamagnetic effects of superconductivity?

Tags: superconductivity, neutrons

It is well known that an applied magnetic field to a superconducting material produces a diamagnetic response due to the induced screening currents.

Neutrons used as a probe for magnetism and crystal structure interact with nuclear spins as well as unpaired electron spins in orbitals. Would they "see" the effect of the screening current if a magnetic field is applied? More generally, do they not interact with the Cooper pairs since they are by definition closely paired electrons, with total spin 0?

Comment: A deleted answer recommended [this publication](https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/5359/322_physicaB_1998.pdf).

Comment: This paper is very useful for my research, thankyou (and whoever originally posted it) so much!

Comment: Can you explain '*neutrons interact with unpaired electron spins in orbitals*'? If  I understood this sentence, I may have a answer...

Answer (score 1):

Yes - please see https://kops.uni-konstanz.de/bitstream/handle/123456789/5359/322_physicaB_1998.pdf .

> Polarized neutron reflectometry was used for the direct measurement of the magnetic-field penetration depth in
>   a high-temperature (HT,) superconducting film. Two scattering geometries were used. The deduced neutron scattering
>   length density profile gave an exact picture of the composition of the film. The fit to the spin-asymmetry yielded
>   a magnetic-penetration depth of 1400 2 100 A at a temperature of T = 4.8 K along the c-axis oriented perpendicular to
>   the film surface. The model included an intrinsic exponential decay of the penetration depth. For the first time the
>   spin-asymmetry was determined with high resolution over an extended Q-range for a HT,-film. Nb-films were
>   investigated as reference.